# Is there a way to read <script> tag contents

Tags: javascript

I have a site in which there is a `<script>` with a JSON inside. With user script in Tampermonkey, I want to get that JSON to work with it later.

So I thought that I can get it with `getElemntsByTagName("script")`, but I couldn't figure out how to get string out of it.

1. How do you get a string from `getElemntsByTagName("script")`, like `console.log` does?
2. Is there an easier way to do so?

```
window.wpProQuizInitList = window.wpProQuizInitList || [];
window.wpProQuizInitList.push({
  id: '#wpProQuiz_67',
  init: {
    quizId: 67,
    mode: 2,
    globalPoints: 76,
    timelimit: 0,
    resultsGrade: [0],
    bo: 3,
    qpp: 0,
    catPoints: [76],
    formPos: 0,
    lbn: "\u0417\u0430\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0448\u0438\u0442\u0438 \u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442",
    json: {
      "2944": {
        "type": "single",
        "id": 2944,
        "catId": 0,
        "points": 1,
        "correct": [0,0,1,0]
      },
      "2945": {
        "type": "single",
        "id": 2945,
        "catId": 0,
        "points": 1,
        "correct": [0,1,0,0]
      },
      "2946": {
        "type": "single",
        "id": 2946,
        "catId": 0,
        "points": 1,
        "correct": [0,0,1,0]
      },
      …
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get content inside of script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333902/get-content-inside-of-script-tag)

Comment: @YannickEich That question is about using a particular library and does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to get the first `<script>` element; there is no need to obtain a live HTMLCollection to get one element. You can then read its `textContent`.

```
let value = document.querySelector('script').textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName("script")` will return an HTMLCollection which contains a list of script tags. You can get the text of the first script tag like this:

```
getElementsByTagName("script")[0].innerText
```

Comment: [You shouldn't be using `getElemntsByTagName()` in 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) as that is a 20+ year old API that returns a live node list, which hurts performance. And, if you know you want the first `script` found, it's a waste to first find all of them and then throw that collection away just to reference the first one.